# Tooltip opacity bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

I am having some issues with an unchangeable transparency of a bootstrap tooltip in my shiny app. I can create a simple example that works:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(tags$style(type="text/css", ".tooltip.in {
  opacity: 1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}"),
                div(HTML('<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Testericious"></i>')))
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But when I copy the "div" and css part to my real project, it is transparent(ish). I would say opacity is probably 0.5 or less.

My frustration is that I have a lot of code, and I have no idea how to debug this other than creating an entirely new project where I copy bits and bobs from the current project till I have a working application.

If I apply css changes for ".tooltip" through the chrome console nothing changes even though I use 'opacity: 1 !important'.

Any ideas to how I can go about troubleshooting / approach this problem?

**EDIT:**
So I have located that the following bit causes me a problem:

```
rpivotTable::rpivotTableOutput("custom_pivot", height = NULL, width = NULL)
```

And only that bit! Even if I comment out the associated server file, I still get the 'transparency-error'. However when I comment out the above snippet, everything seems fine. I find this odd, as the following example *does not* seem to have problems:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(tags$style(type="text/css", ".tooltip.in {
  opacity: 1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}"),
                div(HTML('<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Testericious"></i>')),
                rpivotTable::rpivotTableOutput("pivot_data", height = NULL, width = NULL) %>% shinycssloaders::withSpinner()
                )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
 output$pivot_data <- rpivotTable::renderRpivotTable({rpivotTable::rpivotTable(mtcars,
                                                                               rows="gear",
                                                                               aggregatorName = "Sum", 
                                                                               cols=c("cyl","carb"),
                                                                               vals = 'drat',
                                                                               locale = 'da')})   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Second edit:**
It might be some sort of twisted interaction between multiple javascript parts.
Essentially there are 2 tabs (2 ui files) that causes different things.

App sourced with tab1 (sortableTableOutput) but not tab2:
*Causes the background of the tooltip to change to the color white instead of black.*

App sourced with tab2 (rpivotTableOutput) but not tab1:
*Causes the tooltip to appear as an element of the page - that is at the bottom of the screen extending the page (however you can't really see it as you need to hover on the tooltip icon while scroling - unless you zoom out).

App sourced with both tab1 and tab2:
*Causes the tooltip to become somewhat transparent*

Comment: Hi, it is almost impossible to know where this comes from with the info you provide. I ran your app with all the packages loaded and didn't have this problem. My only advice is to make a copy of your app and delete parts progressively so that you can narrow down the source of the problem. If you use shiny modules, this should be easier: comment the ui and server calls to the modules, and un-comment them progressively. Also, your css is applied on `.tooltip.in` but you said that you tried to modify `.tooltip` in Chrome console. Did you try to modify `.tooltip.in` in console?

Comment: Most likely your CSS somewhere else is interfering with this.  Give an ID to this div, so that it only applies to this tooltip.

Comment: It is so weird though. When I comment this in my code: 
`rpivotTable::rpivotTableOutput("pivot_data", height = NULL, width = NULL)` 
the tooltips are fully visible. But when I insert an rpivotTable in my example above, I do not seem to have any transparency problems.

Answer (score 0):

Give an `id` to the div.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(tags$style(type="text/css", "#my_fa_info .tooltip.in {
  opacity: 1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}"),
  div(id="my_fa_info" , HTML('<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Testericious"></i>')))
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem. When I open the chrome console and mark the row with the div, there is no css-styling for the tooltip. But it seems that this problem ALSO occurs when the rpivotTable has been out-commented (that is when the tooltip is actually showing).